# How to resume a thread without the native ResumeThread api?

Tags: c++, inline-assembly, native-code

I'm going to resume a thread in my program without the use of native [`ResumeThread()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685086%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) api.

My thread in my program is suspended, and now I want it to resume. How to do that?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. `ResumeThread()` is the only way to resume a suspended thread.  Otherwise, don't suspend the thread to begin with.  Use a waitable object instead, such as from `CreateEvent()`, and make the thread wait on it to "suspend" and then signal it when ready to "resume".

Comment: Either you give some context or this question gets closed for not making any sense.

Comment: @MuhammadAkhtar Your edit was not correct. Don't do that.

Comment: In fact i'm going to write my own function like ResumeThread() api to resume a thread in c++ or inline assembly.